# operation on selection of true value in dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in which a  column is having true and false values.I want to add a new column to the datframe which will show the sum of some other columns if the value is false and if it is true the sum  of other columns.

Comment: Please provide minimal but sufficient information in order to see what you have or what you have done and the desired output required! Like how your dataframe look like and what are the columns you want to sum and on what basis!